# Setting the resolution of QTile as a wayland compositor

Tags: manjaro, wayland

## Context

I am running Manjaro with KDE and would like to experiment with Wayland compositors (specifically QTile and dwl but QTile seems like a better starting point). I installed QTile, switched to VT3 and ran `qtile start -b wayland`. It started, but at a lower resolution than my display (everything was blurry and too large). I have used Hyprland before, and for that there were properties in the config file that described the scaling, resolution, and layout of the monitors, however I cannot find anything similar in the QTile documentation (the "screens" variable seems to only control status bars). I do not have a very good understanding of how Wayland compositors work, but short of learning how to program how to program one from scratch, I've had some trouble finding learning resources. Is there a compositor-independent way of managing display settings, or is it controlled entirely by the compositor's config? And if so, is there any way to change QTile's display settings (such as resolution and scaling) when running it as a Wayland compositor?
I do apologise if this question is really stupid and I'm misunderstanding some fundamental thing, but I have searched for a few days and failed to find anything that made me understand.

```
# Technical info
Distro: Manjaro
Desktop environment: KDE
QTile version: 0.23.0
```

I do have a `NVidia` GPU which I did not know was a terrible idea when I bought it and sadly I do not have  the money to buy another.

## TL;DR

How do I change the display settings (resolution, scaling, arrangement of screens) when running QTile as a Wayland compositor?